# Get reason that LoadLibrary cannot load DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, loadlibrary

On Linux and Mac, when using `dlopen()` to load a shared library that links to another library, if linking fails because of a missing symbol, you can get the name of the missing symbol with `dlerror()`. It says something like

```
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "foo"
```

On Windows, when using `LoadLibrary()` to load a DLL with a missing symbol, you can only get an error code from `GetLastError()` which for this type of issue will always be 127. How can I figure out which symbol is missing, or a more verbose error message from `LoadLibrary()` that explains why the function failed?

Comment: Short answer - you can't, because Windows simply does not provide that kind of detail.

Comment: Do you know about [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/)?

Comment: Fine-grained loader diagnostics are available, but they are not enabled by default.  They are only useful to a programmer, not an end-user.  Google "windows show loader snaps" to find out how to do it.  Practically any half-decent Q+A about this error documents this btw, be sure to google some more.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you post a link to said "half-decent Q+A about this error"? If it exists, I likely would have found it.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way using the [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) terminal. Other methods might work with GUI software.
A major caveat is that this can't be done in pure C/C++ and released for end users. It's for developers only, but it's better than nothing.

Install [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) by downloading the Windows SDK and unchecking everything except Debugging Tools.
I could be wrong, but it seems that installing this software installs a hook into the Windows kernel to allow `LoadLibrary()` to write verbose information to stderr.

Open the MSYS2 Mingw64 terminal as an administrator and run

```
'/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Debuggers/x64/gflags.exe' -i main.exe +sls
```

This prints the following to the terminal to confirm that the registry has been changed.

```
Current Registry Settings for main.exe executable are: 00000002
    sls - Show Loader Snaps
```

Use `-sls` instead of `+sls` if you need to undo, since I believe that the change takes place for all programs called `main.exe` in Windows globally, not just for your file.

Then running `main.exe` *should* print debug information to stderr, but since I'm debugging an `-mwindows` application, it's not working for me.

But for some reason, running the binary with MSYS2's gdb allows this debug information to be printed to stderr.
Install `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb` with MSYS2 and run `gdb ./main.exe` and type `run` or `r`.
Search for a section similar to the following.

```
warning: 1ec8:43a0 @ 764081125 - LdrpNameToOrdinal - WARNING: Procedure "foo" could not be located in DLL at base 0x000000006FC40000.
warning: 1ec8:43a0 @ 764081125 - LdrpReportError - ERROR: Locating export "foo" for DLL "C:\whatever\plugin.dll" failed with status: 0xc0000139.
warning: 1ec8:43a0 @ 764081125 - LdrpGenericExceptionFilter - ERROR: Function LdrpSnapModule raised exception 0xc0000139
    Exception record: .exr 00000000050BE5F0
    Context record: .cxr 00000000050BE100
warning: 1ec8:43a0 @ 764081125 - LdrpProcessWork - ERROR: Unable to load DLL: "C:\whatever\plugin.dll", Parent Module: "(null)", Status: 0xc0000139
warning: 1ec8:43a0 @ 764081171 - LdrpLoadDllInternal - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000139
warning: 1ec8:43a0 @ 764081171 - LdrLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000139
```

Great! It says `Procedure "foo" could not be located in DLL` so we have our missing symbol, just like in POSIX/UNIX's `dlopen()`.

Comment: This requires the target EXE/DLL to be compiled with debug symbols in a format that `gdb` can handle. Unfortunately, not all 3rd party C/C++ compilers for Windows use such formats.

Comment: Loader snaps diagnostics aren't printed to stderr. The go to the debug output (`OutputDebugString`) that can be observed using a debugger like Visual Studio or a standalone tool like [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview).

Comment: This functionality is not exclusive to MSYS terminal. You can configure gflags from any kind of command prompt. And you can observe the output in any kind on debugger, not just GDB.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from Remy Lebeau is technically correct, determining the missing symbol from GetLastError() is still possible on a Windows platform. To understand what exactly is missing, understanding the terminology is critical.

Symbol:

> When a DLL is compiled, it's functions are referenced by symbols.
>   These symbols directly relate to the functions name (the symbols are
>   represented by visible and readable strings), its return type, and
>   it's parameters. The symbols can actually be read directly through a
>   text editor although difficult to find in large DLLs.[DLL Symbols - C++ Forum](http://cplusplus.com/forum/articles/16073/)

To have a missing symbol implies that a function within cannot be found. If this error occurs prior to using GetProcAddress(), then it's possible that any number of functions cannot be loaded due to missing prerequisites. This means it is possible that a library that you are attempting to load also requires a library that the first cannot load. These levels of dependency may go on for an unknown number of layers, but the only answer that GetLastError() can determine is that there was a missing symbol. One such method is by using [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine the missing library the first library requires. Once all required libraries are available and can be found by that library (which can be its own can of worms), that library can be loaded via LoadLibrary().

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can set up Dependency Walker to say which symbol is missing? "Dependency Walker missing symbol" returns no relevant results in Google, and Dependency Walker's manual has no mention of the word "symbol".

Comment: I updated my comment to expand on the concept of symbols. Symbols represent functions and if those functions are missing libraries they depend on, those symbols cannot be loaded. Basically, it's likely that you're missing libraries that your loaded library requires in order to provide all symbols listed in the symbol table. Dependency Walker helps you identify which libraries that your library needs.

Comment: Dependency Walker has been largely rendered useless with the introduction of Windows 8, at least the static import resolution. I don't know whether the dynamic (profiling) mode is affected as much.